# Ldap Configuration file to connect locally.?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

In `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` file we have to add domain information like this

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
checkpoint      1024 15
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
```

Let us suppose i will want to connect locally means connect ldap server by another application which is running in same machine where ldap is even then i have to add `suffix` and    `rootdn`    information in   `slapd.conf` or we can give ipaddress in place of domainname?

It is mandatory machine DNS should be in configured for that machine ? It is not possible to run ldap without domainname?

Answer (score 1):

`suffix` in config says what node (DN) is the "head" of your directory information tree (DIT).
`rootdn` is something like "root login" for LDAP server (all user logins in LDAP are DNs).

You also can add users to your DIT and use those credentials to connect to LDAP server.

You don't need to have configured DNS on your host to connect to LDAP server. All you need is LDAP server address and (probably) user credentials for your application.

Easy way to check connection params is to use [ldapsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch):

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldap://127.0.0.1:389 -D uid=JohnDoe,ou=users,dc=my-domain,dc=com -W -b dc=my-domain,dc=com
```